# Flutter fix text overflow issue inside column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the following code which is showing text overflow error. I would like the wrap inside the space. I have tried applying expanded on the Text but it doesn't work.

```
return Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Center(child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                child: Center(child: Text(entitlements.value.identifier, textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
              )),
            ],
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            //shape: ,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(boxRadius),
                topRight: Radius.circular(boxRadius),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(boxRadius),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(boxRadius)),
            color: dGreen,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          bottom: 35.0,
          child: Container(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle, color: blue, size: 50.0,)),
                entitlements.value.identifier=='50 People'
                    ? Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    getText('50 People'),
                    getSubText('50 People')
                  ],
                )
                    :entitlements.value.identifier=='20 People'
                    ? Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    getText('20 People'),
                   getSubText('20 People')
                  ],
                )
                    : Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    getText('10 People'),
                    getSubText('10 People')
                    ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(boxRadius),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(boxRadius),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(boxRadius),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(boxRadius)),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

[image]

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library
> ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The following
> assertion was thrown during layout: A RenderFlex overflowed by 56
> pixels on the right.
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:    Row
> Row:file:///Users/D/Desktop/FlutterApps/myapp/lib/CustomWidgets/stackedBoxSubscription.dart:41:20
> : To inspect this widget in Flutter DevTools, visit:
> http://127.0.0.1:9101/#/inspector?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A57033%2FbBcIVimG4UU%3D%2F&inspectorRef=inspector-52090
> The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal. The
> edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the
> rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually
> caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
>
> Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to
> force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space
> instead of being sized to their natural size. This is considered an
> error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot
> be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available
> space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it
> in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like
> a ListView.
>
> The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#5c08b OVERFLOWING
> ...  parentData:  (can use size) ...  constraints:
> BoxConstraints(w=374.0, h=79.0) ...  size: Size(374.0, 79.0) ...
> direction: horizontal ...  mainAxisAlignment: start ...  mainAxisSize:
> max ...  crossAxisAlignment: center ...  textDirection: ltr ...
> verticalDirection: down

Answer (score 1):

Do like this
Wrap your Row widget with Expanded Widget

```
Expanded(
  flex:1,
  child : Row(
    children: [
      //your code and widgets
    ]
  )
)
```

Mark this answer as correct if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:inside  Row widget, Wrap your column inside Flexible.
Solution 2: use AutoSized Text package available on pub.dev

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).